# angular 2: attaching string with property binding

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to attach string with propery binding

for example my object is

```
{
  "name": "The Walking Dead",
  "imageUrl": "/title/tt1520211/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=2240084122&pf_rd_r=1Q5ZRDHSA2ZK5S6Q31WN&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=tvmeter&ref_=chttvm_tt_1",
  "rating": "8.6"
},
```

as I dont have base url in imageUrl field I want to attach it in angular template url

template:

```
<tbody *ngFor="let prod of products">
<tr >
  <td><img [src]="'www.example.com/'+{{prod.imgUrl}}" alt=""></td>
  <td>{{prod.name}}</td>
  <td>{{prod.rating}}</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
```

I'm trying to add example.com for my ImageUrl in my template field and I'm unable to add base URL

Im expecting url to be baseurl+path

```
www.example.com/title/tt1520211/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=2240084122&pf_rd_r=1Q5ZRDHSA2ZK5S6Q31WN&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=tvmeter&ref_=chttvm_tt_1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont have to use curly brackets. Just do simple:

`<img [src]="'www.example.com/' + prod.imgUrl">`

---

`<tag [someAttr]="someValue">`

In angular this means that `someValue` will be evaluated (just like inside `{{}}`) and assigned to `someAttr`, so for string part you should use quotes like in pure JS

---

`<tag someAttr="someString">`

means that `someString` will be parsed like template, (you must use `{{}}` to evaluate imgUrl) and assigned to `someAttr`

in your e.g. `<img src="www.example.com/{{prod.imgUrl}}">`

---

`someAttr` is @Input() property in
component, or HTMLElement property,

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this:

```
<img src="www.example.com/{{prod.imgUrl}}" alt="">
```

Answer (score 2):

or you can try

```
<td><img [src]="'www.example.com/' + prod.imgUrl" alt=""></td>
```

without the curcly braces